# Error Message: "No module named 'django.core.urlresolvers".Even though I've replaced the module

Tags: python, django, database

I was trying to create tables in my database by executing the command on the django shell in the Windows CLI

```
migrate.py syncdb
```

It returned with the error message

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error importing debug panel debug_toolbar.panels.request: "No module named 'django.core.urlresolvers'"
```

After reading up to resolve my problem I discovered it is because the module django.core.urlresolvers is not available in versions of python higher than 1.9 and django.urls is the more suitable module. I replaced the former module in my code with the latter

```
from django.urls import reverse
```

and somehow still manage to get the same error.

How do I resolve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you python manage.py migrate?

Comment: You sure replace it in every file it may be?

Comment: The command manage.py migrate basically executes the same thing but yeah it returns the same error. Thanks though.

Comment: I'm using the atom editor and used Shift + ctrl + f to locate and replace it within the whole project.

Comment: Did you restart the server?

Comment: I restarted the server.

Comment: having same issue--did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, Try these steps

1. Delete the virtual environment folder.
2. Create a fresh virtual environment.
3. Install all the requirements,
4. implement make migrations
5. implement migrations.

Check if everything is working by running the server. This worked for me, hope it helps.